# Shell execute grep command within sed replacement not as expected

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

I am working on some deployment script for Kubernetes, and want to execute a single command to replace some "Template Variables" in yaml file using sed.

I have the following (example, shortened yaml file) input file where i want to do the replacements:
input.txt

```
CONTAINER_ADDITIONAL
spec:
  selector:
    app: CONTAINER_NAME
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: EXPOSED_PORT
```

Also, I've got the following Dockerfile where i want to get the `EXPOSE` port number from to be inserted into the `EXPOSED_PORT`:
Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest

EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR /app
```

I have now tried to use different approaches to get the port number `3000` (from Dockerfile) inserted into the `EXPOSED_PORT`
(`CONTAINER_NAME` and `CONTAINER_ADDITIONAL` are working, they are in the example file for completenes with the command below).

The following commands can be executed directly in the shell and give the wanted result (`3000`):
`cat Dockerfile | grep EXPOSE | cut -d" " -f2` -> there may be still the `\n`
`cat Dockerfile | grep EXPOSE | cut -d" " -f2 | tr -d "\n"` -> previously mentionned `\n` removed
`grep EXPOSE Dockerfile | cut -d" " -f2` -> with `\n`
`grep EXPOSE Dockerfile | cut -d" " -f2 | tr -d "\n"` -> without `\n`
`grep EXPOSE Dockerfile | awk '{print $2}'` -> with `\n`, uses single quote - not an option?
`grep EXPOSE Dockerfile|tr -d -c 0-9` -> without `\n`, not prefered (when situation would exist of multiple port numbers separated by spaces)
`grep -Po "(?<=^EXPOSE )\w*$" Dockerfile` -> with `\n`, not prefered (multiple port numbers)
`grep -Po "(?<=^EXPOSE )\w*$" Dockerfile | tr -d "\n"` -> without `\n`

**HOWEVER:**

`sed -e 's@CONTAINER_NAME@some-container-name@g;s@CONTAINER_ADDITIONAL@cat some_config.txt@e;s@EXPOSED_PORT@grep EXPOSE Dockerfile | cut -d" " -f2 | tr -d "\n"@e' input.txt`

Does not work for the `EXPOSED_PORT`. The other two variables `CONTAINER_NAME` and `CONTAINER_ADDITIONAL` work (the cat gets executed, content of `some_config.txt` is being put in there)

No matter which of the above mentioned commands that are working and giving the correct result directly in shell, they do not work when executed in sed (the awk for sure not, because of single quotes).

The output I get is:

```
inserted_content_of: some_config.txt
some_more_inserted_content_from: some_config.txt
spec:
  selector:
    app: some-container-name
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
sh: 1: port:: not found
```

The expected output that i want to have:

```
inserted_content_of: some_config.txt
some_more_inserted_content_from: some_config.txt
spec:
  selector:
    app: some-container-name
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong with the sed command?
Is there some explanation what goes wrong?
How can i solve this issue?

Comment: How about sed -e "s@CONTAINER_NAME@some-container-name@g;s@CONTAINER_ADDITIONAL@$(cat some_config.txt)@e;s@EXPOSED_PORT@$(grep EXPOSE input.txt | cut -d" " -f2 | tr -d \"\n\")@e" input.txt?

Comment: ```sed: -e expression #1, char 78: unterminated `s' command``` and even when trying to revert back to the single quotes for sed and undoing the escape for double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think, that

```
grep EXPOSE input.txt | cut -d" " -f2
```

is a good way to get the portnumber (the `\n` is not appended when used in another command). Perhaps you should save it first before your next step.

```
portnumber=$(grep EXPOSE input.txt | cut -d" " -f2)
echo "The portnumber will be [${portnumber}]."
```

I will replace your `grep` command with `echo "4444"`, showing the problem with your nested command.
With `@e` you ask `sed` to execute the resulting string after processing `s@EXPOSED_PORT@echo "4444"@`. The line with EXPOSED_PORT is

```
port: EXPOSED_PORT
```

So `sed` is trying to execute `port echo "4444"`, and complains about the command `port`.
When you want to use the `@e`, you should use something like

```
sed -r 's@(.*)(EXPOSED_PORT)(.*)@echo "\1$(echo "4444")\3"@e' input.txt
```

And you thought it would be easy? Try like this:

```
sed 's@EXPOSED_PORT@'${portnumber}'@' input.txt
# or when you really want to squeeze your command into this line
sed 's@EXPOSED_PORT@'$(echo "4444")'@' input.txt
```

Or look at `awk`:

```
awk -v port=${portnumber} '/EXPOSED_PORT/ {$2=port} 1' input.txt
# or nested
awk -v port=$(echo "4444") '/EXPOSED_PORT/ {$2=port} 1' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are not changing the whole line when changing the port but rather just a section of the line. Because the leading "port:" has been left, sed tries to execute this along with the grep command and hence the error. To overcome, this, search and replace the whole line and so:

```
sed -e 's@CONTAINER_NAME@some-container-name@g;s@CONTAINER_ADDITIONAL@cat some_config.txt@e;s@^.*EXPOSED_PORT@echo "      port: $(grep EXPOSE input.txt | cut -d" " -f2 | tr -d "\n")"@e' input.txt
```

Echo out the leading port: along with the expanded grep command.

Comment: Great and short explanations, thank you very much. Your command works perfectly fine, however the flexibility is greater with accepted answer regarding the spacing before the `port:`

Comment: No worries. A like would be much appreciated ;@)

Comment: I Upvoted / Liked, your answer but becuase my account is relativly new, it doesnt display it, but it gets counted :)